# How to differentiate $(y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$ w.r.t. $\beta$ and useful formulas in this context?

Tags: calculus

How do I differentiate the following w.r.t. $\beta$
$$
f(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)
$$
where $y,\beta$ are vectors and $X$ is a matrix? Should I consider this as a directional derivative? So, to calculate this, do I use the formula:
$$
\nabla f \cdot \beta ?
$$
Or is it
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta} = \nabla f?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(\beta)=\|y-X\beta\|^2$.
Now we indeed use the formula
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\beta}=\nabla f\cdot\beta:=\mathrm{d}f(\beta)[\beta]$$
since $\beta$ is a vector. We have
$$\|y-X\beta\|^2=\|y\|^2-2y\cdot X\beta+\|X\beta\|^2$$
and for any vector $h$, we have
$$y\cdot X(\beta+h)=y\cdot X\beta+y\cdot Xh$$
and
$$\|X(\beta+h)\|^2=X(\beta+h)\cdot X(\beta+h)=\|X\beta\|^2+2X\beta\cdot Xh+\|Xh\|^2.$$
Then, the differential of $f$ at $\beta$ in the direction $h$ is given by
$$\mathrm{d}f(\beta)[h]=-2y\cdot Xh+2X\beta\cdot Xh$$
and thus
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\beta}=\nabla f\cdot\beta=\mathrm{d}f(\beta)[\beta]=-2y\cdot X\beta+2X\beta\cdot X\beta=2\left(\|X\beta\|^2-y^T X\beta\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the textbook answer is $-2X^T(y-X\beta)$. Shouldn't I use $\partial f / \partial \beta = \nabla f$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a X. I edit, just a second.

Comment: So there is still a slight difference between my answer and the one in your textbook. I have never seen the formula $\partial f/\partial\beta=\nabla f$, but see in your book if it is defined somewhere. Anyway, the only difference is the dot product with $\beta$.